# How to do Unit Testing for a controller structured upon Clean Architecture and CQRS?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, cqrs

I have a Product API for which I mean to do Unit Testing via xUnit.net and Moq. I'm totally new to Unit Testing btw. I've seen a couple of videos on Unit Testing for controllers via Repository pattern, but This one is a CQRS. below is the presentation layer (API). I call commands or queries from the Application layer.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllProducts()
{
    var products = await _mediator.Send(new GetAllProductsQuery());
    return Ok(products);
}
```

I wanted to test the Controller, so I added a reference to the API on the *xUnit* project. I tried to structure the commands and queries in the Application layer from the group up based on repository pattern but It failed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming (for the sake of simplicity) that `_mediator` is an instance of this `IMediator` interface, injected via the Controller's constructor:

```
public interface IMediator
{
    Task<IReadOnlyCollection<Product>> Send(GetAllProductsQuery getAllProductsQuery);
}
```

you can write a unit test of the Controller action like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAllProductsReturnsOk()
{
    var td = new Mock<IMediator>();
    var expected = new[] { new Product() };
    td.Setup(m => m.Send(It.IsAny<GetAllProductsQuery>())).ReturnsAsync(expected);
    var sut = new ProductsController(td.Object);

    var result = await sut.GetAllProducts();

    var ok = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<OkObjectResult>(result);
    Assert.Equal(expected, ok.Value);
}
```

This test uses my standard [test role names](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/11/30/name-by-role) and [AAA layout heuristic](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/06/24/a-heuristic-for-formatting-code-according-to-the-aaa-pattern).

Comment: Thanks Mark. You have been a great help since I joined Stack! I tried almost the same code. A constructor is already defined in the controller, but I got an error on defining the sut variable. So I added another constructor to the controller and this time I got a System.NullReferenceException error on debugging!

Comment: My mistake! I should've defined a separate constructor for only IMediator. Thanks

Comment: the unit test it's testing multiple things but not what is in the name of the test.